# Query on 3 tables with two outer joins

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a problem with running a T-SQL query to join 3 tables, dimStores, fctSales, dimDates.

I need to retain all rows from dimStores (list of selected stores) and dimDates (selection of dates) and matching details from fctSales. I can only join them via fctSales table that has keys for stores and dates.

I tried left outer join to get full list of selected Stores and then Right outer join to get all Dates but never was able to get both at the same time.

dimStores (StoreName)
fctSales (StoreName, DateKey)
dimDates (Date)

```
SELECT 
  st.StoreName
 ,sa.SaleItem
 ,dd.DateKey 
From dimStores as st
  Left outer join fctSales as sa on st.StoreName = sa.StoreName
  right outer join dimDates as dd on dd.DateKey = sa.DateKey
WHERE dd.DateKey between 20150101 and 20150115
  and sa.StoreName in ('Aka','Bink','Gil')
```

Please help

Comment: make the last join in your query `FULL JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

give it a try
with the left join with the fact you did in fact keep the Stores but with the right join on date, only the stores with data on that date would be considered

To keep all the stores on every possible date full outer join both to get all the combinations and only then join with the data.

```
SELECT 
  st.StoreName
 ,sa.SaleItem
 ,dd.DateKey 
From dimStores as st
full outer join dimDates as dd on 
    1=1
Left outer join fctSales as sa on 
    st.StoreName = sa.StoreName and
    dd.DateKey = sa.DateKey
WHERE 
    dd.DateKey between 20150101 and 20150115 and 
    sa.StoreName in ('Aka','Bink','Gil')
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly, exactly what I wanted. Could you just explain what is 1=1 ?

Comment: its only so that All rows match each other since 1=1 is Always True. Every row from dimStores will match with dimDates just like you would with a CROSS JOIN. It produces the Cartesian product of the tables involved.